Adding image with given extent and given projection string to OpenLayers fails
Given an image, I have the following data provided:
Citing/translating the docs: "The proj-string for the grid in the WGS84 earth model is:"
+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=10 +a=6378137 +b=6356752.3142451802 +no_defs +x_0=543196.83521776402 +y_0=3622588.8619310018

and the extent is given as
   lat         long
NE 55.84543856 18.73161645
SW 45.69642538 3.566994635

I register the "proj-string" like:
  useGeographic();
  proj4.defs('ABC:123', '+proj=stere ...');
  register(proj4);

And later I use:
  const src = new ImageStatic({
    url: canvas.toDataURL(),
    projection: 'ABC:123',
    imageExtent: wnWGS84extent, //coordinates as above
  });

The image does not appear. But if I merely replace 'ABC:123' with 'WGS84' I see the image, albeit a bit too far east.
Given the image appears if I use 'WGS84', I assume I am registering it wrong or the proj string is broken and doesn't even get parsed.
A hint how I can fix it or, even better, debug this would be great.

imageExtent must be in the source projection, so you need to transform it transformExtent(wnWGS84extent, 'WGS84', 'ABC:123') useGeographic applies to view and layer coordinates and extents.

This, at least, lets me see the image, with my projection ABC:123, though now it seems to be stretched in west-east direction. I tried to find some introductory documentation providing the background from which I could read things like you write "imageExtent must be in the source projection". Maybe a different question.

Checking the numerical values of the transformed extent, comparing to the image pixel dimension and guess-fixing one of the values provides a belivable result. Back-transforming the guess-fixed image coordinates shows that the the SO longitude is probably wrong.

transformExtent returns an extent that enclosed all 4 transformed corners.  Maybe you only need SW and NE? [...ol.proj.transform(wnWGS84extent.slice(0, 2), 'WGS84', 'ABC:123'), ...ol.proj.transform(wnWGS84extent.slice(2, 4), 'WGS84', 'ABC:123')]
